# How to send data from form to controller

Tags: php, opencart

In my web store, built on OpenCart, I've created absolutely new template and controller for it. Path is template/common/orderForm. In this template there is a very simple contact form.

Template code (not very much, I didn't even include the header).

```
<!doctype html>

<div style="width: 723px;">
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="your_name"><br>
Ваше e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Заказать">
</form>
</div>
```

Well, the biggest problem is that I don't know how to send data from form to controller. All I need to understand is how to do that. The other part, like sending form data via email, I can handle myself. Honestly, I totally can't understand OpenCart system.

Controller code

```
<?php  
class ControllerCommonOrderForm extends Controller {
    public function index() {
$this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_title'));
$this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/orderForm');
$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->config->get('config_title');

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl')) {
$this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
} else {
$this->template = 'default/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
}

$this->children = array(
'common/column_left',
'common/column_right',
'common/content_top',
'common/content_bottom',
'common/footer',
'common/header'
);

$this->response->setOutput($this->render());


/* Input data check */
$your_name = $this->config->get('your_name');
echo $your_name;
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
/* Устанавливаем e-mail адресата */
$myemail = "the.eolithic@gmail.com";
/* Создаем новую переменную, присвоив ей значение */
$message_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте!
Вашей контактной формой было отправлено сообщение!
Имя отправителя: $your_name
E-mail: $email
Конец";
/* Отправляем сообщение, используя mail() функцию */
$from  = "From: $yourname <$email> \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($myemail, $message_to_myemail, $from);
?>
<p>Ваше сообщение было успешно отправлено!</p>
<p>На <a href="index.php">Главную >>></a></p>
<?php
/* Если при заполнении формы были допущены ошибки сработает
следующий код: */
function check_input($data, $problem = "")
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Пожалуйста исправьте следующую ошибку:</p>
    <?php echo $myError; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    exit();
}
}
}
?>
```

Everytime I go to the form page, I get these errors. And I don't even press the submit button.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: yourname in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\catalog\controller\common\orderForm.php on line 40Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\catalog\controller\common\orderForm.php on line 41
```

Thank you for your attention. I hope you know how to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try this...

your template file should be this:

```
<!doctype html>

<div style="width: 723px;">
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
Your name: <input type="text" name="your_name"><br>
Your e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>
</div>
```

This has just been changed to english....

Your controller file should be this (I have changed some of it to english)

```
<?php  
class ControllerCommonOrderForm extends Controller {
    public function index() {
$this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_title'));
$this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/orderForm');
$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->config->get('config_title');

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl')) {
$this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
} else {
$this->template = 'default/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
}

$this->children = array(
'common/column_left',
'common/column_right',
'common/content_top',
'common/content_bottom',
'common/footer',
'common/header'
);

$this->response->setOutput($this->render());

/* Check if form has been submitted */
if( isset($_POST['your_name']) )
{
/* Input data check */
$your_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["your_name"]);
echo $your_name;
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
/* Set the e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "the.eolithic@gmail.com";
/* Create a new variable by assigning a value to it */
$message_to_myemail = "Hello!
Your contact form has been sent a message!
Sender's name: $your_name
E-mail: $email
end";
/* Send a message using the mail () function */
$from  = "From: $your_name <$email> \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($myemail, $message_to_myemail, $from);
?>
<p>Your message has been successfully sent!</p>
<p>At <a href="index.php">Home >>></a></p>
<?php
/* If you are filling out the form mistakes were made work
the following code: */
function check_input($data, $problem = "")
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Please correct the following error:</p>
    <?php echo $myError; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    exit();
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Let me know if that helps...

Comment: Thank you! Code works great! By the way, for newbies like me: you should install mail server (for example, Sendmail, as I did) to gain the ability to send mails. The code will not work without Sendmail.

Comment: A little mistake was found in the code above: for some reasons $your_name = $this->config->get('your_name');  doesn't work. It gets empty string. But if you replace this line with $your_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["your_name"]); everything is great!

Comment: @eoLithic woops I forgot to include that... post updated... thanks

Comment: Please read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109347/how-to-update-customer-tin-number-in-opncart @eoLithic